# Why does a new expo init produce "export default function" rather than "export default class"? in App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo

I think that I have been doing nothing differently but all of a sudden when executing

```
expo init my_App_Name
```

the default App.js file produced contains

```
export default function App(){}
```

instead of

```
export default class App extends React.Component{render()}
```

As a result, I am always needing to rewrite.  Any idea why this occurs?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you take a look at the source code https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/templates/expo-template-blank/App.js that's the template it's using when creating new project. If you want to have a class component instead you should go with `bare minimal` template (second to the last on the list of available templates when running `expo init` command), instead of `blank` one.